# How can I read a bytes string (i.e., gzipped text file read) to a file handle object in Python?

Tags: python, string, file, byte, gzip

I cant figure out how to treat this string representation of gzipped text as a file handle object.

```
import requests
def read_url(url, params=None, **kwargs):
    r = requests.get(url, params=params, **kwargs)
    return r.text

# Read gzipped file from URL
gzipped_string = read_url("https://github.com/jolespin/walkthroughs/raw/main/data/microbiome__acute-malnutrition/sequences.fasta.gz")

# Create a file handle for it
for line in StringIO(gzipped_string):
    print(line)
    # �4�_sequences.fasta�]�r�̍��i�-iFsq��G�}��@�?ͦ4�v8l���&+@fE�����^������0-���K"%U�ϯ>ʟ���)��xy���E?����l���]xy���������ϟ��>ߍ�J�ee���˻,�����~������*�'�
    break
```

Comment: gzipped data is not text and should not be treated as such. You should be using `r.content`, not `r.text`. What exactly do you mean by "file handle object"?

Comment: The function that I am using downstream uses a file handle as input.

Comment: Python has file "objects", and you can get file descriptors from file objects and sockets, I'm not aware of file "handles" in python.

Comment: Instead, how can I convert that string to its human readable text form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def read_url(url, params=None, **kwargs):
    r = requests.get(url, params=params, **kwargs)
    return r.content # Note the change based on @president-james-k-polk

gzipped_string = read_url("https://github.com/jolespin/walkthroughs/raw/main/data/microbiome__acute-malnutrition/sequences.fasta.gz")

for line in StringIO(gzip.decompress(gzipped_string).decode("utf-8")):
    print(line)
    # >Otu000009
    break
```